# Ignore spaces at the begining and at the end of a line

Tags: regex

I want a regex to ignore the blank spaces at the beginning and at the end of a line, for instance:

```
 A B C             - matches "A B C"
    AA             - matches "AA"
  AA BB CC A       - matches "AA BB CC A"
  A   B   C        - matches "A   B   C"
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
[a-zA-Z]+(\s*)[a-zA-Z]+
```

Comment: You may use `\S.*\S`

Comment: Or `\S(?:.*\S)?` to allow a single non-whitespace char lines.

Comment: Why not use `string.strip()`/`string.trim()` or whatever the equivalent is for your language?

Comment: I don't understand the question. In most (all?) cases regexs search for a substring, which would ignore leading/trailing spaces automatically. Or do you want a regex that matches a line _exactly_ while ignoring leading/trailing spaces?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to match `[a-zA-Z]` with zero or more whitespaces between the characters but not at the start or at the end you might use a capturing group:

[`^ *([a-zA-Z ]*[a-zA-Z]) *$`](https://regex101.com/r/cVd7M5/1)

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert the start of the line
- `*` Match zero or more times a whitespace (To match a whitespace character you could use `\s*` instead)
- `(` Capturing group

  - `[a-zA-Z ]*[a-zA-Z]` Match zero or more times a lower or uppercase character or a whitespace followed by a lower or uppercase character
- `)` Close capturing group
- `*` Match zero or more times a whitespace
- `$` Assert the end of the line